# failed to build some targets for AOSIP

Tags: android, custom-rom

my question is similar to [#### failed to build some targets (1 seconds) ####](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62446053/failed-to-build-some-targets-1-seconds) but there were no further updates.

I'm trying to compile the image for AOSIP branch ten for OnePlus 7T and I used the following commands:

```
repo init -u git://github.com/AOSiP/platform_manifest.git -b ten

repo sync --force-sync --no-tags --no-clone-bundle

git clone https://github.com/AOSiP-Devices/device_oneplus_hotdogb.git

git clone https://github.com/AOSiP-Devices/device_oneplus_hotdogb.git ./device/oneplus/hotdogb

source build/envsetup.sh

lunch aosip_hotdogb-userdebug

make api-stubs-docs-update-current-api
```

Initially, when I did the lunch, I realised that the /prebuilts/go/darwin-x86 was missing and so I did "git clone [https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/go/darwin-x86"](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/go/darwin-x86%22). That allowed me to lunch successfully. However, when I run the make command I was met with the build failure with the following messages.

```
/bin/bash: nproc: command not found
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=10
AOSIP_VERSION=10-Quiche-hotdogb-20201220
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosip_hotdogb
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-2a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
BUILD_ID=QQ3A.200805.001
============================================
[ 29% 50/170] link out/soong/.bootstrap/gotestrunner/obj/a.out
FAILED: out/soong/.bootstrap/gotestrunner/obj/a.out
GOROOT='prebuilts/go/darwin-x86' prebuilts/go/darwin-x86/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link -o out/soong/.bootstrap/gotestrunner/obj/a.out.tmp  out/soong/.bootstrap/gotestrunner/obj/gotestrunner.a && if cmp --quiet out/soong/.bootstrap/gotestrunner/obj/a.out.tmp out/soong/.bootstrap/gotestrunner/obj/a.out; then rm out/soong/.bootstrap/gotestrunner/obj/a.out.tmp; else mv -f out/soong/.bootstrap/gotestrunner/obj/a.out.tmp out/soong/.bootstrap/gotestrunner/obj/a.out; fi
runtime.main_main·f: function main is undeclared in the main package
[ 30% 51/170] link out/soong/.bootstrap/soong_env/obj/a.out
FAILED: out/soong/.bootstrap/soong_env/obj/a.out
GOROOT='prebuilts/go/darwin-x86' prebuilts/go/darwin-x86/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link -o out/soong/.bootstrap/soong_env/obj/a.out.tmp -L out/soong/.bootstrap/soong-env/pkg out/soong/.bootstrap/soong_env/obj/soong_env.a && if cmp --quiet out/soong/.bootstrap/soong_env/obj/a.out.tmp out/soong/.bootstrap/soong_env/obj/a.out; then rm out/soong/.bootstrap/soong_env/obj/a.out.tmp; else mv -f out/soong/.bootstrap/soong_env/obj/a.out.tmp out/soong/.bootstrap/soong_env/obj/a.out; fi
runtime.main_main·f: function main is undeclared in the main package
[ 30% 52/170] link out/soong/.bootstrap/loadplugins/obj/a.out
FAILED: out/soong/.bootstrap/loadplugins/obj/a.out
GOROOT='prebuilts/go/darwin-x86' prebuilts/go/darwin-x86/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link -o out/soong/.bootstrap/loadplugins/obj/a.out.tmp  out/soong/.bootstrap/loadplugins/obj/loadplugins.a && if cmp --quiet out/soong/.bootstrap/loadplugins/obj/a.out.tmp out/soong/.bootstrap/loadplugins/obj/a.out; then rm out/soong/.bootstrap/loadplugins/obj/a.out.tmp; else mv -f out/soong/.bootstrap/loadplugins/obj/a.out.tmp out/soong/.bootstrap/loadplugins/obj/a.out; fi
runtime.main_main·f: function main is undeclared in the main package
[ 31% 53/170] link out/soong/.bootstrap/gotestmain/obj/a.out
FAILED: out/soong/.bootstrap/gotestmain/obj/a.out
GOROOT='prebuilts/go/darwin-x86' prebuilts/go/darwin-x86/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link -o out/soong/.bootstrap/gotestmain/obj/a.out.tmp  out/soong/.bootstrap/gotestmain/obj/gotestmain.a && if cmp --quiet out/soong/.bootstrap/gotestmain/obj/a.out.tmp out/soong/.bootstrap/gotestmain/obj/a.out; then rm out/soong/.bootstrap/gotestmain/obj/a.out.tmp; else mv -f out/soong/.bootstrap/gotestmain/obj/a.out.tmp out/soong/.bootstrap/gotestmain/obj/a.out; fi
runtime.main_main·f: function main is undeclared in the main package
22:33:57 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (2 seconds) ####
```

Thank you.

Comment: I followed @TheHardGamer 's solution and solved the issue but I cant build the last obj:
[100% 1/1] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -b out/soong -n out -d out/soong/build.ninja.d -globFile out/soong/.bootstrap/build-globs.ninja -o out/soong/build.ninja Android.bp
error: system/extras/libfec/Android.bp:3:1: "libfec" depends on undefined module "libsquashfs_utils"
22:39:58 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please state the system you are building it on, moreover whenever you clone anything from https://android.googlesource.com/ , always specify the branch name using -b else you will end up cloning the default branch of the repo. For ex, if you are cloning darwin for a Android Q/10 Rom, clone it like
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/go/darwin-x86 -b android-security-10.0.0_r49

You can find the branch names on left bottom of the website.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using a macOS Catalina Version 10.15.7. Your suggestion solved the problem. But I'm faced with another issue.

Comment: libsquashfs_utils is defined [here](https://github.com/AOSiP/platform_system_extras/blob/60577b1d6bd6d87c8d5e96f8176a17c740ab4021/squashfs_utils/Android.bp#L4)